# Номер мне незнаком или не знаком?

Tags: краткое-прилагательное

"Номер мне незнаком" или в данном случае необходимо писать раздельно "не знаком", а слитное написание было бы корректно с лучше, например, "я незнаком с этим *****"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: *Номер мне **незнаком**. Я **незнаком** с ним.*

1. ***Незнакомый*** — это прилагательное, ***незнаком*** — краткое прилагательное, практически во всех случаях слова  пишутся слитно с НЕ, в том числе при наличии зависимых слов.

Это видно и по примерам в толковом словаре, причем для всех значений этого слова.

**НЕЗНАКОМЫЙ**,  1. **Неизвестный**, не встречавшийся прежде. Н. человек. Заблудиться и попасть в н-ые места. Мне незнакома эта фамилия. 2. Не испытанный кем-л., **чуждый** кому-л. Ей незнакома ложь. Ему незнакомо чувство страха. Им овладела н-ая до сих пор апатия. 3. **обычно кратк.** Не испытавший, не изведавший чего-л., не имеющий познаний, опыта в чём-л. Она незнакома с жизнью. Он незнаком с правилами вежливости. Кто-л. незнаком с работой реактора. 4. **обычно кратк.** Не состоящий в знакомстве с кем-л. Я его видела на собраниях, но лично незнакома. Они много слышали друг о друге, но были незнакомы. **Мы с вами пока ещё незнакомы.** <Незнакомо, нареч. (1 зн.). Он выглядел и жестикулировал как-то н.

2. Но раньше (обычно до реформы 1956 год) **раздельное написание НЕ  при наличии зависимых слов** встречалось часто, например: Тот, конечно, отвечает, что он **не знаком** с этим термином. [епископ Александр, 1944]
3. В настоящее время  иногда допускается раздельное написание НЕ **в обособленных оборотах:** А потом опять приехал следователь, а с ним еще один мужчина, **мне не знакомый**. [Н. Леонов, А. Макеев. Гроссмейстер сыска (2003)]

По Розенталю в этом случае происходит сближение с причастиями.